# Mapping graph to coordinates to minimize connection length

Tags: c++, recursion, math, combinations, graph-theory

While working on my hobby electronics project I've designed a couple of logic schematics using discreet logic ICs.

Example (don't mind the current package assignments):
[image: Logic schematic]

This particular schematic uses ICs that contain multiple elements gates of each type:

- CD4011 (4 x 2NAND gates) - 4 pcs.
- CD4023 (3 x 3NAND gates) - 2 pcs.
- CD4012 (2 x 4NAND gates) - 2 pcs.
- CD4049 (6 x INV gates)   - 1 pcs.
- CD4030 (4 x 2XOR gates)  - 1 pcs.
- Total number of ICs: 10 pcs.

All the gates in all the packages are interchangeable and any gate can be placed in my schematic in place of another.

Usually ICs are placed physically on PCB in grid arrangement. So in this example a grid 2x5 is used.

For example:

[image: Grid example]

After we know the exact arrangement of ICs on this grid we can map the original schematic to this grid in such a manner as to minimize total connection length.

To represent schematic connections I've decided to use Boost adjacency_list:

```
enum ICType {
    BLANK,CD4011,CD4012,CD4023,CD4030,CD4049
};
struct vertex_info {
    ICType IC;
    unsigned int X;
    unsigned int Y;
};
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, vertex_info> ICGraph;
typedef graph_traits<ICGraph>::edge_iterator edge_iterator;
```

The ICGraph is created manually (vertex IDs correspond to the numbers on each logic element in the schematic above, X,Y coordinates are initialized to 100) :

```
ICGraph ICGroupAGraph() {



    typedef std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> Edge;
    std::vector<Edge> edgeVec;
    // CS1-CS2 connections
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(0, 1));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(2, 3));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(3, 4));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(1, 7));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(4, 7));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(5, 7));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(6, 7));

    //WRRD connections
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(8, 9));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(11, 12));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(9, 10));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(12, 10));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(10, 16));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(13, 16));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(14, 16));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(14, 15));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(3, 13));// Shared with CS1-CS2

    //V1-V2-V4 | V3 connections
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(17, 18));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(18, 19));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(19, 20));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(22, 20));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(20, 21));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(22, 23));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(21, 25));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(24, 25));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(15, 24)); // Shared with WRRD

    //OE connections
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(26, 28));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(27, 28));

    //S3N connections
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(29, 30));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(30, 31));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(33, 34));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(31, 35));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(32, 35));
    edgeVec.push_back(Edge(34, 35));

    ICGraph g(edgeVec.begin(), edgeVec.end(), 36);
    g[0].IC = CD4030; g[0].X = 100; g[0].Y = 100;
    g[1].IC = CD4011; g[1].X = 100; g[1].Y = 100;
    g[2].IC = CD4011; g[2].X = 100; g[2].Y = 100;
    g[3].IC = CD4030; g[3].X = 100; g[3].Y = 100;
    g[4].IC = CD4011; g[4].X = 100; g[4].Y = 100;
    g[5].IC = CD4011; g[5].X = 100; g[5].Y = 100;
    g[6].IC = CD4011; g[6].X = 100; g[6].Y = 100;
    g[7].IC = CD4012; g[7].X = 100; g[7].Y = 100;
    g[8].IC = CD4011; g[8].X = 100; g[8].Y = 100;
    g[9].IC = CD4049; g[9].X = 100; g[9].Y = 100;
    g[10].IC = CD4011; g[10].X = 100; g[10].Y = 100;
    g[11].IC = CD4011; g[11].X = 100; g[11].Y = 100;
    g[12].IC = CD4049; g[12].X = 100; g[12].Y = 100;
    g[13].IC = CD4011; g[13].X = 100; g[13].Y = 100;
    g[14].IC = CD4023; g[14].X = 100; g[14].Y = 100;
    g[15].IC = CD4049; g[15].X = 100; g[15].Y = 100;
    g[16].IC = CD4023; g[16].X = 100; g[16].Y = 100;
    g[17].IC = CD4023; g[17].X = 100; g[17].Y = 100;
    g[18].IC = CD4049; g[18].X = 100; g[18].Y = 100;
    g[19].IC = CD4011; g[19].X = 100; g[19].Y = 100;
    g[20].IC = CD4011; g[20].X = 100; g[20].Y = 100;
    g[21].IC = CD4049; g[21].X = 100; g[21].Y = 100;
    g[22].IC = CD4012; g[22].X = 100; g[22].Y = 100;
    g[23].IC = CD4049; g[23].X = 100; g[23].Y = 100;
    g[24].IC = CD4011; g[24].X = 100; g[24].Y = 100;
    g[25].IC = CD4011; g[25].X = 100; g[25].Y = 100;
    g[26].IC = CD4030; g[26].X = 100; g[26].Y = 100;
    g[27].IC = CD4011; g[27].X = 100; g[27].Y = 100;
    g[28].IC = CD4023; g[28].X = 100; g[28].Y = 100;
    g[29].IC = CD4030; g[29].X = 100; g[29].Y = 100;
    g[30].IC = CD4011; g[30].X = 100; g[30].Y = 100;
    g[31].IC = CD4012; g[31].X = 100; g[31].Y = 100;
    g[32].IC = CD4023; g[32].X = 100; g[32].Y = 100;
    g[33].IC = CD4023; g[33].X = 100; g[33].Y = 100;
    g[34].IC = CD4011; g[34].X = 100; g[34].Y = 100;
    g[35].IC = CD4012; g[35].X = 100; g[35].Y = 100;
    return g;
}
```

Arrangement of ICs is generated using an algorithm and transformed to IC map using two functions:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<ICType, unsigned int>>> TransformArraytoGrid(std::vector<ICType> &inputArray, unsigned int gridsizeX, unsigned int gridsizeY) {
    
    std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<ICType, unsigned int>>> out;
    if (gridsizeX * gridsizeY != inputArray.size()) {
        std::cout << "Grid size is different from Array size!" << std::endl;
        return out;
    }
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < gridsizeX; x++) {
        std::vector<std::pair<ICType, unsigned int>> ySub;
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < gridsizeY; y++) {
            unsigned int ICsize;
            switch (inputArray[x * gridsizeY + y]) {
                case BLANK:   ICsize = 0; break;
                case CD4011:   ICsize = 4; break;
                case CD4012:   ICsize = 2; break;
                case CD4023:   ICsize = 3; break;
                case CD4049:   ICsize = 6; break;
                case CD4030:   ICsize = 4; break;
                default:    ICsize = 0; break;
            }
            ySub.push_back(std::make_pair(inputArray[x * gridsizeY + y], ICsize));
        }
        out.push_back(ySub);
    }
    
    return out;
}

std::map<ICType,std::map<std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>, unsigned int>> TransformGridtoMap(std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<ICType, unsigned int>>> &grid)
{
    std::map<ICType, std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>> out;

    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < grid.size(); x++) {
        
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < grid[x].size(); y++) {
            out[grid[x][y].first][std::make_pair(x, y)] = grid[x][y].second;
        }
        
    }
    return out;
}
```

To find the optimal connection arrangement I've wrote the following recursive algorithm:

```
std::vector<ICGraph> MapGraphtoGrid(std::map<ICType, std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>> &ICmap, ICGraph &inICGraph) {
    std::vector< ICGraph> out;
    
    bool subCycleStarted = false;

    std::pair<edge_iterator, edge_iterator> ei = edges(inICGraph);
    
    for (edge_iterator edge_iter = ei.first; edge_iter != ei.second && subCycleStarted == false; ++edge_iter) {
        if (inICGraph[source(*edge_iter, inICGraph)].X == 100 && inICGraph[source(*edge_iter, inICGraph)].Y == 100 && subCycleStarted == false) {
            ICType currentIC = inICGraph[source(*edge_iter, inICGraph)].IC;
            unsigned int nV = source(*edge_iter, inICGraph);
            std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::iterator it;
            std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>> availableICs;
            double sourceMinDistance = 1000;
            for (it = ICmap[currentIC].begin(); it != ICmap[currentIC].end(); it++) {
                if (it->second > 0) {
                    unsigned int curDistanceX = it->first.first;
                    unsigned int curDistanceY = it->first.second;
                    double curDistance = curDistanceX * curDistanceX + curDistanceY * curDistanceY; // if source vertex was not assigned during previous iterations - place it as close to 0,0 as possible
                    if (curDistance <= sourceMinDistance) {
                        if (curDistance < sourceMinDistance) {
                            availableICs.clear(); //This way only connections with minimal length will remain
                        }
                        
                        availableICs.push_back(std::make_pair(it->first.first, it->first.second));
                        sourceMinDistance = curDistance;
                    }

                }
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < availableICs.size(); i++) {
                subCycleStarted = true;
                ICGraph subinICGraph = inICGraph;
                std::map<ICType, std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>> subICmap = ICmap; //copy IC map for next iterations
                subinICGraph[source(*edge_iter, subinICGraph)].X = availableICs[i].first; //assign coordinates in graph to available ICs
                subinICGraph[source(*edge_iter, subinICGraph)].Y = availableICs[i].second;
                subICmap[currentIC][availableICs[i]]--;//decrement number of IC elements available at this coordinate;
                std::vector< ICGraph> subLevelGraphArray = MapGraphtoGrid(subICmap, subinICGraph); //run next cycle for all possible connections
                out.insert(std::end(out), std::begin(subLevelGraphArray), std::end(subLevelGraphArray));
            }

        }
        if (inICGraph[target(*edge_iter, inICGraph)].X == 100 && inICGraph[target(*edge_iter, inICGraph)].Y == 100 && subCycleStarted == false) {
            ICType currentIC = inICGraph[target(*edge_iter, inICGraph)].IC;
            unsigned int nV = target(*edge_iter, inICGraph);
            std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::iterator it;
            std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>> availableICs;
            double targetMinDistance = 1000;
            unsigned int sourceX = inICGraph[source(*edge_iter, inICGraph)].X;
            unsigned int sourceY = inICGraph[source(*edge_iter, inICGraph)].Y;
            for (it = ICmap[currentIC].begin(); it != ICmap[currentIC].end(); it++) {
                if (it->second > 0) {
                    
                    unsigned int curDistanceX = it->first.first;
                    unsigned int curDistanceY = it->first.second;
                    double curDistance;
                    if (sourceX != 100 && sourceY != 100) {
                        curDistance = std::sqrt((sourceX - curDistanceX) * (sourceX - curDistanceX) + (sourceY - curDistanceY) * (sourceY - curDistanceY)); // minimize distance from source vertex
                    }
                    else {
                        curDistance = (double)curDistanceX;
                    }

                    if (curDistance <= targetMinDistance) {
                        if (curDistance < targetMinDistance) {
                            availableICs.clear(); //This way only connections with minimal length will remain
                        }
      
                        availableICs.push_back(std::make_pair(it->first.first, it->first.second));
                        targetMinDistance = curDistance;
                    }

                }
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < availableICs.size(); i++) {
                subCycleStarted = true;
                ICGraph subinICGraph = inICGraph;
                std::map<ICType, std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>> subICmap = ICmap; //copy IC map for next iterations
                subinICGraph[target(*edge_iter, subinICGraph)].X = availableICs[i].first; //assign coordinates in graph to available ICs
                subinICGraph[target(*edge_iter, subinICGraph)].Y = availableICs[i].second;
                subICmap[currentIC][availableICs[i]]--;//decrement number of IC elements available at this coordinate;
                std::vector< ICGraph> subLevelGraphArray = MapGraphtoGrid(subICmap, subinICGraph);//run next cycle for all possible connections
                out.insert(std::end(out), std::begin(subLevelGraphArray), std::end(subLevelGraphArray));
            }

        }
        
    }
    if (subCycleStarted == false) {
        out.push_back(inICGraph); // if no sub cycle was started return the input graph;
    }
    

    return out;
}
```

The above algorithm does work and produce an array of possible graph mappings. After that the ICGraph with the least sum of connection lengths is selected and printed out:

```
The optimal solution length:36.9574
    
Vertex #0 Type: CD4030  Coordinates:    3,1
Vertex #1 Type: CD4011  Coordinates:    2,1
Vertex #2 Type: CD4011  Coordinates:    0,1
Vertex #3 Type: CD4030  Coordinates:    3,1
Vertex #4 Type: CD4011  Coordinates:    3,0
Vertex #5 Type: CD4011  Coordinates:    0,1
Vertex #6 Type: CD4011  Coordinates:    0,1
Vertex #7 Type: CD4012  Coordinates:    1,1
Vertex #8 Type: CD4011  Coordinates:    0,1
Vertex #9 Type: CD4049  Coordinates:    1,0
Vertex #10 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    2,0
Vertex #11 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    2,0
Vertex #12 Type:CD4049  Coordinates:    1,0
Vertex #13 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    2,1
Vertex #14 Type:CD4023  Coordinates:    0,0
Vertex #15 Type:CD4049  Coordinates:    1,0
Vertex #16 Type:CD4023  Coordinates:    0,0
Vertex #17 Type:CD4023  Coordinates:    0,0
Vertex #18 Type:CD4049  Coordinates:    1,0
Vertex #19 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    2,0
Vertex #20 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    2,0
Vertex #21 Type:CD4049  Coordinates:    1,0
Vertex #22 Type:CD4012  Coordinates:    1,1
Vertex #23 Type:CD4049  Coordinates:    1,0
Vertex #24 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    2,1
Vertex #25 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    2,1
Vertex #26 Type:CD4030  Coordinates:    3,1
Vertex #27 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    3,0
Vertex #28 Type:CD4023  Coordinates:    4,1
Vertex #29 Type:CD4030  Coordinates:    3,1
Vertex #30 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    3,0
Vertex #31 Type:CD4012  Coordinates:    4,0
Vertex #32 Type:CD4023  Coordinates:    4,1
Vertex #33 Type:CD4023  Coordinates:    4,1
Vertex #34 Type:CD4011  Coordinates:    3,0
Vertex #35 Type:CD4012  Coordinates:    4,0
```

While I'm happy with the obtained result I feel like the algorithm I'm using for mapping graph to a particular grid is not ideal and can have following problems:

- Possible mappings might not include the "most" optimal solution because edges are iterated consecutively and only the minimal length connections between source and target vertex are considered
- For some grid arrangements the branching in this algorithm is extreme and produces ~100000 possible graph mappings which takes a lot of processing time
- Combined with grid arrangement variation generation this approach can take around an hour to produce the solution for IC grids 6x2 size

I would appreciate if someone could share their thoughts on how to improve this algorithm or suggest an alternative approach for graph mapping that does not have listed limitations. Unfortunately I was not able to find a similar problem elsewhere on the internet. If you have a reference to a math paper/program/etc that deals with similar problem I'd be happy to have a look.

Comment: *this approach can take around an hour to produce the solution for IC grids 6x2 size* -- I am assuming you are timing a release, optimized build, and not an unoptimized "debug" build?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes of course. Debug builds for this algorithm run much slower.

Comment: Interesting problem.  Not something that I can answer off the top of my head.  Essentially this is a graph theory problem.  So, I would use a graph theory library that provides methods for route finding.  My own preference is PathFinder ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder ).  The first step is to load your schematic into the cGraph class.  FYI I have made a start on that in https://github.com/JamesBremner/IConnector

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: From the examples, it seems that your graphs are directed, acyclic graphs (DAGs). A commonly used hierarchical layout algorithm for such graphs is the Sugiyama algorithm ("dot" in graphviz & derivative software). The Sugiyama layout is a heuristic that minimises edge crossings and total edge length while being quite fast.

Comment: Did you come up with something? I'm also interested in this, during my Bachelor's in EE I wanted to come up with algorithms/methods to improve chip design (I guess Nvidia already [did this with ML](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/nvidia-tech-uses-ai-to-optimize-chip-designs-up-to-30x-faster)..), if you put the "library" somewhere I might try it out myself on some old files